# How do you mock a function which has decorator apply to it in a unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
@lolcat_decorator1
@loldog_decorator2
@lolrat_decorator3
def lolanimal(*args, **kwargs):
  ....
```

I am sure I will unit-test those decorators separately. But these decorators will do stuff to the parameters passed to `lolanimal` first, and then `lolanimal` will do stuff to those modified parameters (one of those decorators may insert new keyword arguments to `**kwargs`.)

So what's the best way to mock it?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using decorators?  This seems like a textbook case for inheritance.

Comment: Somebody in my team figure it was a good idea to use decorators. Well... I can't go back. Too many codes are using that :( I mean decorators are just functions. I guess I can patch them...just wondering if people actually have a better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought would be to create a `_lolanimal` method that encapsulates all the actual functionality of `lolanimal` and then just make `lolanimal` a pass through wrapper around `_lolanimal`.  Then you could just run all your tests against `_lolanimal` with data you fully control.

You also might be able to create a second decorator that would come before the first that would read a config value or something for some sort of testing mode that would override the `lolspecific` decorator if the config value is true...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's quite useful. Does first method means I can;'t use decorators?

Comment: @CppLearner You'd just decorate the wrapper instead of the implementation method.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that you should consider the decorators as part of the implementation of the function, and unit test the "function", hopefully you won't need to inject the dependencies into those decorators though - if you do, then Silas Ray's answer would need to be considered.