# How to mock nested decorated function in Python?

Tags: python, python-mock

I have the following python file `flow.py`

```py
from viewflow.flow import flow_job
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
@flow_job
def populate_proxmox_info(activation):
    ...
```

In unit test I would like to mock this `populate_proxmox_info` method. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812570/how-to-mock-a-decorated-function), I tried to mock like this:

```py
from flow import flow_job

class TestCase1(TestCase):

    @patch.object(flow_job, 'populate_proxmox_info')
    def test_auto_change(self, *args):
        ...
```

But it complains `AttributeError: <function flow_job at 0x1121ce840> does not have the attribute 'populate_proxmox_info'`

Also tried

```py
@patch('viewflow.flow.flow_job.populate_proxmox_info') 
# and
@patch('flows.flow_job.populate_proxmox_info')
```

gets the same error

Comment: Have you tried `@patch('flow_job.populate_proxmox_info')`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work